# HTML table rounded corner

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS. I want to achieve rounded-corner for my table and it is not working. Any ideas how can I make it work?
Here is my CSS for table:

```
    table {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size:13px;
        color:white;
    }

    td {
        border: none;
    }
```

Currently, it looks like this:
[image]

And I want the corner of the table to be rounded.
Many thanks.

Comment: use border-radius css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the rounded table using the `border-radius` CSS attribute based on `border-collapse: separate` as follows.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  
  background: red;
  
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

td {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can probably leave `-moz-border-radius: 10px;` off at this point in time, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use border radius on the table.

```
 table {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-radius: 20%;
        font-size:13px;
        color:white;
    }

    td {
        border: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give `border-radius` to make table border rounded so try this :

```
table {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-radius:50px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size:13px;
        color:white;
    }

    td {
        border: none;
    }
```